Failed to scan for dependencies from entries: index.html" Error after Running npm run dev
I am encountering an issue while trying to run my Vue.js project with Vite. After executing the command npm run dev, the server fails to start, and I receive the following error:
VITE v5.4.3  ready in 949 ms

➜  Local:   http://localhost:3000/
➜  Network use --host to expose

Error: Failed to scan for dependencies from entries:
C:/xampp/htdocs/fill rouge/my-vue-resourceHub/index.html

The service was stopped: write EPIPE
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\fill rouge\my-vue-resourceHub\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:993:26
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (C:\xampp\htdocs\fill rouge\my-vue-resourceHub\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:622:9)
    at afterClose (C:\xampp\htdocs\fill rouge\my-vue-resourceHub\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:613:28)
    at onwriteError (node:internal/streams/writable:597:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)


Steps I've Taken:
-Deleted node_modules and reinstalled dependencies:
Ran rm -rf node_modules and npm install with no success.
-Checked vite.config.js:
Verified the Vite configuration but didn’t find any issues related to paths or entry points.
-Verified the project structure:
My project structure seems fine with index.html at the root level and src/ containing the Vue components.
Project Information:
Vite Version: v5.4.3
Node Version: (please replace with your node version, e.g., v20.15.0)
npm Version: (please replace with your npm version, e.g., v10.8.1)
Operating System: Windows 10
Directory Structure: (please provide a brief overview if relevant)

Try to change the node.js  version .

Hi, welcome. why do you think that the author used AI?

Also, please read how to answer
